# What are the things to take into consideration while implementing a CException c++ class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have tried a simple C++ CException implementation class, deriving from std::exception. What did I do wrong, what should I add more, what should I improve on? What is it more to c++ exceptions that one should take into consideration? The aim is to make it as much platform independent as possible. The code follows:
Edited:

```
class CeException: public std::exception {
public:
    char* getascii(const wchar_t* msg)
    {
        char* pasc = new char[wcslen(msg) + 1 ];
        wcstombs(pasc, msg, wcslen(msg) + 1);
        return pasc;
    }
    CeException(const wchar_t* msg, char* pasc = NULL ):
    exception(pasc = getascii(msg))
    {

        delete[] pasc;
    }
    CeException(const string msg) 
    {   

    }
    virtual ~CeException()
    {       
    }
    BOOL GetErrorMessage(LPTSTR lpszError, UINT nMaxError, PUINT pnHelpContext = NULL )
    {

        const char* pasc = this->what();

        wchar_t* puni = new wchar_t[strlen(pasc)+1];
            mbstowcs(puni,pasc, strlen(pasc) + 1);

        wcscpy_s(lpszError,nMaxError, puni);
        delete[] puni;
        return 0;
    }
    void Delete()
    {
        delete this;
    }


};
```

I have edited with my final implementation, using your indications.

Comment: I know that the base std::exception class stores it's own error mesage, and that my CException stores a different one. How does it generate that message?

Comment: You should learn more C++ first.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you people. Enlight me please.

Comment: If you want a platform independent exception class, just use `std::exception`. If you're implementing your own, then it is (hopefully) because you require something *more* than platform independence. But based on the requirements you've given us (literally *only* that it should be platform independent), the only sane answer is "just use `std::exception`")

Comment: beside my practical needs, I also want to understand how this exception thing works, so I thought about a practical example on which people could comment on.

Comment: @firexzanderr, I mean, you should learn basic topics before delving into more advanced ones. You have not yet learned about how `throw` works or about how base class constructors are called.

Comment: Platform-independent starts with not using Windows-isms like LPSTR, UINT, PUINT, and all the rest of those upper-case names.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.SE

Comment: [std::exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) does not store an error message, MSVC is non-standard in this respect. Your `callBaseCt()` function will not compile (unless there's a `using namespace std;` somewhere) and even if it does, it's not doing what you expect it to. Also, your throwing constructors are weird. Just construct the exception object and let the caller worry about throwing. Lastly, don't name your class `CException` (or at least put it in a namespace) if you want to use it with MFC, since that has a `CException` class also.

Comment: @PeteBecker +1. I didn't know that. I am just a learning guy.

Comment: Please don't use `#define tstring std::wstring`, use a typedef instead! That is if you must support ASCII character sets - I would suggest you would be fine to just use `std::wstring` exclusively.

Comment: @Praetorian, I do have a using namespace std, so you're saying that the base class won't store my message, is the message that I see if I call the what() function from std::exception generated on the spot?

Comment: @fire You can only call a base constructor from the constructor initializer list. Your code is creating a temporary `std::exception` object that gets destroyed at the end of the statement. I don't understand why you want to call the base constructor anyway since you have a `string` member for storing the error message.

Comment: I didn't knew that it wouldn't store my message, I will eliminate the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't need to implement methods inside exception class, so it might look something like this:

```
class YourException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    explicit YourException(const std::string & msg) :
        std::runtime_error(msg)
    {
    }
};
```

I don't understand the reasons to have other methods.

You should not throw exception from it's constructor. Instead, client code should throw your exception:

```
    throw YourException("Some error");
```

Comment: I have tried to mimic MFC CException, with its methods.

Comment: @firexzanderr - MFC is **not** cross-platform

Comment: I know that is not cross-platform, that is why I have tried to replicate

Comment: You asked the most independent implementation... Why would you need to mimic MFC? It's not the world's best framework, especially concerning exceptions (AFAIK they throw exceptions by pointers)

Comment: Because I have to modify a project that uses MFC to not use MFC anymore and I am trying as much as possible to provide some similar data types with same functionalities that the project initially made us of from MFC classes.

Comment: Ah, I've been there before: having to replicate the behaviour of a badly designed class. You should have said that in your question and you would have got answers instead of complaints.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just thought that I may as well get most I can on the topic as I already have to deal with it. It's a really painful job, behavior replication, not rewarding at all.

Comment: @firexzanderr - re: "that is why I have tried to replicate" - you have my sympathy. MFC is a badly designed library. It's primary purpose is to make Windows programs more portable across the various incarnations of Windows.